# Oracle Trigger How to get Inserted value's parameter

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have a question while studying Oracle Database's triggers.

First of all, I created two tables like below:

```
**[Employee]**
(empno NUMBER, VARCHAR2 (20), deptno NUMBER, salary NUMBER)
**[Department]**
(deptno NUMBER, dname VARCHAR2 (20))
```

Employee deptno refers to Department's deptno.

The trigger I want to create is to calculate the salary average of the data with deptno, such as inserted deptno.

For example, suppose I run the following code.

```
INSERT INTO employee values (1000, 'PAUL', 10, 4000);
```

Then Trigger would like to have the following output:

```
Department [10]'s average of Salary = <avg (salary)>
```

But I do not know how to pass inserted row's parameter in the Trigger.

Does anyone have a good way for me?

Comment: I know you're just learning the basics, but think before creating any triggers, do not create them lightly.  They can be very expensive (among other pitfalls).  For example, if you have say 10 million rows in this table, do you really want to run an aggregate function on all rows each time a row is inserted, updated, or deleted?  In most cases, if a trigger can be avoided, I'll avoid it.  This is definitely not a situation for a trigger.

Comment: Thank you. I will be familiar with your advice.

Comment: Heres a good read from [Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o58asktom-101055.html), which explains more on the pitfalls I talked about.

Comment: What do you mean, the "trigger would have the following output"? Output to where, and for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that if I use the AFTER INSERT keyword in the trigger, I get an 'ORA-04091' error because the contents of the table are changing. So I found out that I had to use before insert to get the result.
This is not the correct way, but I was able to express the output I wanted.

It was very simple. Before the table is changed (BEFORE INSERT Keyword), I store the sum of the columns in the variable to get the average.
Then add the new value to the variable using the ': NEW' keyword.

When I used this method, I did not get the 'ORA-04091' error because the table is still before the change.

Thanks to a lot of people, I've found that this is not a good way to write in a trigger.
However, I am thinking about this problem and I have learned a lot of internal actions such as the cost of triggers and when to call them.

Thank you again for all the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is not the best place for such things, but it can be done with [compound trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005):

```
create or replace trigger avg_dept_salary for insert on employee compound trigger

  type tb_num is table of number;
  v_depts tb_num := tb_num();
  v_sum number;

before each row is 
  begin
    if :new.deptno not member of v_depts then
      v_depts.extend();
      v_depts(v_depts.count()) := :new.deptno;
    end if;
  end before each row;

after statement is
  begin
    for i in 1..v_depts.count() loop
      select avg(salary) into v_sum from employee where deptno = v_depts(i);
      dbms_output.put_line('Department '||v_depts(i)||' average salary: '||v_sum);
    end loop;
  end after statement;

end;
```

Test:

```
insert into employee 
  select 1001, 'PAUL', 10, 1000 from dual union all
  select 1002, 'ANNE', 10, 1700 from dual union all
  select 1003, 'MARY', 10,  900 from dual union all
  select 1004, 'JOHN', 20, 1200 from dual;
```

Output for each affected department:

```
Department 10 average salary: 1900
Department 20 average salary: 1200
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it soon.

Comment: I tried your source code, but i got an error message - ORA-04091: table employee is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.

Answer (score -1):

This makes no sense to be implemented as a trigger.  This is just a simple SQL query :

```
select deptno ,avg(salary)
from employee
group by deptno
```

Comment: Sorry. But I want to print that as a trigger.

Comment: You may question why I use that method, but I just want to know how. I am not just looking for a practical way.

Comment: You can't "print" from a trigger.  What happens when you have 10 concurrent updates going in?

Comment: The 'print' that i talked means DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(). I could output using AFTER INSERT when I simply calculated the overall average without using any other parameters.